# CSS3 translate: using percent values

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm attempting to understand why in this codepen the two boxes aren't perfectly aligned.

https://codepen.io/mburke05/pen/BYXOGP

**html**

```
<div class="div_one">pixel</div>
<div class="div_two">percent</div>
```

**css**

```
.div_one {
  border: solid red;
  transform: translate(70px, 20%) ;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
}

.div_two {
  border: solid blue;
  transform: translate(50%, 30%) ;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

I thought I understood that, when using %'s rather than pixel or other values, that the % value was based on the height of the element itself rather than the % of the parent (which in this case would be the viewport.)

However, to achieve what I believe is alignment, I would need to set `translate(48%, 30%)` as the value. Why is this? Isn't 70 50% of 140, or is there more to it than I'm understanding.

As a follow-up, can anybody explain why this is the preferred way of centering an object vertically mathematically?

Comment: you have border you need to consider in the width/height ... add box-sizing:border-box and both will be the same

Comment: this does look correct, can you explain why the two would be offset though? aren't they identical except for the transform? why does border-box change that?

Comment: border are included in the width so total width is not 140px as you think but 146px --- so 50% is not 70px but 73px

Comment: great explanation; thanks. i can see that with dev tools now! can you also explain why transform(-50%, -50%) is used in creating the vertical centering pattern?

Comment: simply because by default we consider top-left corner to position element ... if you create an inverse translation by half width/height we make it consider the center of the element so you position the center of an element that's why it get centred

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
  box-sizing : border-box
}
```

By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This means that when you set width and height you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.

Read More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score -1):

```
.div_one {
  border: solid red;
   width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
}

.div_two {
  border: solid blue;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

remove CSS property "transform", Both Div will align perfectly and if you want to move the position of the box means use padding or margin and if you want to fix in box position then use Position property